# Ant: fileset with dynamic root directory

Tags: ant

So the ant fileset, if I want it to be a separate task referenced via its ID by various targets, I need to declare the root "dir" attribute in that fileset. ie:

```
<fileset id="my.fileset" dir="myDir">
    <includes name="**/*" />
</fileset>
```

In my case, I have a set of files that have the same relative paths, but depending on various build configurations, they'll have different root directories. ie:

```
${dyanmic.root.dir}/com/name/package/file.class
```

I'm trying to have a fileset of the relative paths to the files, but where every time I reference the fileset I can set a different "dir" property to change the root directory. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a [multirootfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/multirootfileset.html) (introduced with Ant 1.9.4).
Just feed all of your rootdirs to the basedirs attribute.
All those dirs will share the nested includes, excludes ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `antcall` and pass the root directory as an argument to a target that contains the `fileset`.

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<project name="project" default="main">


    <target name="callee">
        <echo message="Called... ${FOO}"/>

        <fileset id="my.fileset" dir="${FOO}" includes="**/*" />
        <property name="files" refid="my.fileset"/>
        <echo message="Files: ${files}" />

    </target>

    <target name="caller">
        <echo message="Calling...${FOO}"/>

        <antcall target="callee" inheritall="false">
            <param name="foo" value="${FOO}"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="main" depends="caller" />

</project>
```

Then, run it with `-DFOO=value` to pass in a parameter. So for example, if your project structure is this:

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── a
│   └── b
├── 2
│   ├── c
│   └── d
└── build.xml
```

Then `ant -DFOO=1` will result in:

```
caller:
     [echo] Calling...1

callee:
     [echo] Called... 1
     [echo] Files: a;b

main:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

And `ant -DFOO=2` will result in:

```
caller:
     [echo] Calling...2

callee:
     [echo] Called... 2
     [echo] Files: c;d

main:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```